# implement a trie in cpp

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie

I want to implement a trie in cpp. When I tried to print out all strings in the trie, nothing was printed. But the code was compiled successfully. I think there is something wrong with my insert. My guess is that I should pass by reference somewhere so that the trie is actually modified but I'm not sure where or is that the problem.

My structure:

```
struct Node {
    unordered_map<char, Node*> children;
    bool completeWord;
};

class Trie {
private:
    Node* root;
    void printAll(Node* tmp);
public:
    Trie();
    void insert(string s);
    void printAll();
};

Trie::Trie() {
    root = new Node();
    root->completeWord = false;
}
```

Methods:

```
void Trie::insert(string s) {
    Node* p = root;
    for(char c : s) {
        auto m = p->children;
        if(!m.count(c)) {
            Node* n = new Node();
            m.insert(pair<char, Node*>(c,n));
        }
        else
            p = m[c];
    }
    p->completeWord = true;
}
```

printAll for debugging:

```
void Trie::printAll() {
    printAll(root);
}

void Trie::printAll(Node* tmp) {
    Node* t = tmp;
    auto m = t->children;
    if(!m.empty()){
        for(auto p : m) {
            cout << p.first << " ";
            printAll(p.second); 
        }
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
int main() {
    Trie* t = new Trie();
    string arr[] = {"abc", "abcd", "lmn", "edf"};
    for(string s : arr) 
        t->insert(s);
    t->printAll();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: When you add new Node in insert, you need to update p variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *@Hitobat* and *@Code-Apprentice* I have figured out what I did wrong. In my `insert` it should be:

```
void Trie::insert(string s) {
    Node* p = root;
    for(char c : s) {
        auto &m = p->children; //m -> &m
        if(!m.count(c)) {
            Node* n = new Node();
            m.insert(pair<char, Node*>(c,n));
        }
        p = m[c]; //remove else
    }
    p->completeWord = true;
}
```

`m` was just a pointer to map pairs before, without `&` it would just make changes to copies of those pairs and not to those pairs themselves. So i needed to pass them by reference.
And `p` wasn't updated when new node was inserted.